# Script to Kill All RDP Sessions

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I am trying to create a simple script to kill ALL remote desktop sessions, active or disconnected, without rebooting the server. My server OS is Windows Server 2012R2 with Remote Desktop Services enabled and licensed.

I found a simple batch file script here to do this task: [enter link description here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/428637-log-off-all-terminal-server-session-server-2012)

When I run this script locally on my terminal server, I get an error in the batch file runs that says: Session Disc not found

And only the console user is logged off. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this script?

```
query session >session.txt
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff %%i
del session.txt
```

My Session text file looks like this:

```
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE 
 services                                    0  Disc                        
 >console           Administrator            13  Active                      
                   wcunningham              18  Disc                        
                   kstarkey                 25  Disc                        
 rdp-tcp#11        cyannone                 52  Active                      
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

Comment: In the second line, for example, the third token is `Disc` although you are probably expecting `0`, because there is no entry for `USERNAME`…

Comment: Wouldn’t the third token be ID?

Comment: The third token is the ID when there is a `sessionname` and `username` in the data. The `FOR /F` command delimits output by a space and tab by default.  Those are spaces in between your data.

Comment: Ok. So how can I adjust my script to kill all sessions, regardless if there is a sessioname or username

Comment: The output is fixed-width text, so handle it as such, meaning to use [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to remove the session and user names…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is a good workaround is adding an additional line to handle the disconnected sessions. Since disconnected sessions don't list the sessionname, the ID is at position 2 not position 3 like it is with active session. So adding an additional line that specifies token=2 did the trick:

```
query session >session.txt
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff.exe %%i
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO logoff.exe %%i
del session.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

skip the first 3 lignes and the active user

```
query session >session.txt
for /f "skip=3 eol=> tokens=2," %%i in (session.txt) DO echo %%i
for /f "skip=3 eol=> tokens=3," %%i in (session.txt) DO echo %%i
del session.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As you might have noticed, `SESSIONNAME` and `USERNAME` are sometimes empty, which completely screws positional arguments.
Here is more reliable way of working with queried sessions:

```
> type script.bat
```

```bash
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "skip=1 tokens=* usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`query session`) DO (
    CALL :SESS_PARSE "%%G"
    FOR /f "tokens=1-6 eol= delims=;" %%a IN ("!SESS_DESC!") DO (
        SET sess_is_curr=%%a
        SET sess_user=%%b
        SET sess_id=%%c
        SET sess_state=%%d
        SET sess_type=%%e
        SET sess_name=%%f
    )
    ECHO INPUT: '%%G'
    ECHO DESC : '!SESS_DESC!' 
    ECHO CURR : '!sess_is_curr!'
    ECHO NAME : '!sess_name!'
    ECHO USER : '!sess_user!'
    ECHO SESS : '!sess_id!'
    ECHO STATE: '!sess_state!'
    ECHO TYPE : '!sess_type!'
    ECHO ------------------------------
    rem IF !sess_is_curr! == 1 ECHO Current session ID: '!sess_id!'
)
GOTO :EOF

:SESS_PARSE
    SETLOCAL
    SET "line=%~1"
    rem Extract current session flag
    SET is_curr=0
    IF "!line:~0,1!" == ">" SET is_curr=1
    rem Extract and trim 'SESSIONNAME' field
    SET name=!line:~1,18!
    SET name=!name: =!
    IF "!name!" == "" SET name=-
    rem Extract and trim 'USERNAME' field
    SET user=!line:~19,22!
    SET user=!user: =!
    IF "!user!" == "" SET user=-
    rem Quick-parse the rest of the not so flacky fields
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3" %%a IN ("!line:~42,-1!") DO (SET "sid=%%a" & SET "state=%%b" & SET "type=%%c")
    IF "!type!" == "" SET type=-
    ENDLOCAL & SET "SESS_DESC=%is_curr%;%user%;%sid%;%state%;%type%;%name%;"
GOTO :EOF
```

The output will look as follows:

```
C:\Users\User1>script.cmd
INPUT: ' services                                    0  Disc                        '
DESC : '0;-;0;Disc;-;services;'
CURR : '0'
NAME : 'services'
USER : '-'
SESS : '0'
STATE: 'Disc'
TYPE : '-'
------------------------------
INPUT: '>rdp-tcp#1         User1                     1  Active  rdpwd               '
DESC : '1;User1;1;Active;rdpwd;rdp-tcp#1;'
CURR : '1'
NAME : 'rdp-tcp#1'
USER : 'User1'
SESS : '1'
STATE: 'Active'
TYPE : 'rdpwd'
------------------------------
INPUT: ' rdp-tcp#0         user2                     2  Active  rdpwd               '
DESC : '0;user2;2;Active;rdpwd;rdp-tcp#0;'
CURR : '0'
NAME : 'rdp-tcp#0'
USER : 'user2'
SESS : '2'
STATE: 'Active'
TYPE : 'rdpwd'
------------------------------
INPUT: ' console                                     3  Conn                        '
DESC : '0;-;3;Conn;-;console;'
CURR : '0'
NAME : 'console'
USER : '-'
SESS : '3'
STATE: 'Conn'
TYPE : '-'
------------------------------
INPUT: ' rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen                      '
DESC : '0;-;5536;Listen;-;rdp-tcp;'
CURR : '0'
NAME : 'rdp-tcp'
USER : '-'
SESS : '5536'
STATE: 'Listen'
TYPE : '-'
------------------------------
```

Finally, the complete solution to the problem will look as follows:

```
> type close_remotes.cmd
```

```bash
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "skip=1 tokens=* usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`query session`) DO (
    CALL :SESS_PARSE "%%G"
    FOR /f "tokens=1-6 eol= delims=;" %%a IN ("!SESS_DESC!") DO SET "sess_is_curr=%%a" & SET "sess_user=%%b" & SET "sess_id=%%c" & SET "sess_state=%%d" & SET "sess_type=%%e" & SET "sess_name=%%f"
    CALL :SESS_CLOSE !sess_id! !sess_is_curr! !sess_user!
)
GOTO :EOF

:SESS_PARSE
    SETLOCAL
    SET "line=%~1"
    SET is_curr=0
    IF "!line:~0,1!" == ">" SET is_curr=1
    SET name=!line:~1,18!
    SET name=!name: =!
    IF "!name!" == "" SET name=-
    SET user=!line:~19,22!
    SET user=!user: =!
    IF "!user!" == "" SET user=-
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3" %%a IN ("!line:~41,-1!") DO (SET "sid=%%a" & SET "state=%%b" & SET "type=%%c")
    IF "!type!" == "" SET type=-
    ENDLOCAL & SET "SESS_DESC=%is_curr%;%user%;%sid%;%state%;%type%;%name%;"
GOTO :EOF

:SESS_CLOSE
    rem Do not try to close services session
    IF "%1" == "0" GOTO :EOF
    rem Do not try to close main listeners session
    IF "%1" == "65536" GOTO :EOF
    rem Do not try to close own session
    IF "%2" == "1" GOTO :EOF
    rem Do not try to close session with empty 'USERNAME' field
    IF "%3" == "-" GOTO :EOF
    ECHO Closing Session { id: %1, user: "%3" }
    LOGOFF %1
GOTO :EOF
```